# Generating a list of dictionaries in python using lists that contain duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
case_suite_relation_ids= [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]]
```

and want to generate a list of dictionaries in the following manner

```
[{'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 1}, {'test_case_id': 2, 'test_suite_id': 1},{'test_case_id': 3, 'test_suite_id': 1}, {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 2}, {'test_case_id': 2, 'test_suite_id': 2}, {'test_case_id': 3, 'test_suite_id': 2}, {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 3}]
```

I used the following code

```
keys = ('test_case_id', 'test_suite_id')
list_of_case_suite_relation_rows = [dict(zip(keys, l)) for l in case_suite_relation_ids]
```

but I get the following output

```
[{'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 2}, {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 1}]
```

Any solutions how to solve it ?

Comment: Are you trying to get `[{'test_case_id': case, 'test_suite_id': suite} for case, suite in zip(*case_suite_relation_ids)]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
case_suite_relation_ids= [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]]

d = [{'test_case_id': i, 'test_suite_id': j} for i, j in zip(*case_suite_relation_ids)]

# [{'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 1},
#  {'test_case_id': 2, 'test_suite_id': 1},
#  {'test_case_id': 3, 'test_suite_id': 1},
#  {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 2},
#  {'test_case_id': 2, 'test_suite_id': 2},
#  {'test_case_id': 3, 'test_suite_id': 2},
#  {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 3}]
```

Some people (not me) prefer the functional version:

```
d = list(map(lambda i, j: {'test_case_id': i, 'test_suite_id': j},
             case_suite_relation_ids[0], case_suite_relation_ids[1]))
```

Comment: you could simply write *"Here is the best way:"* +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, Pandas offers a solution:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame(case_suite_relation_ids).T\
      .set_axis(['test_case_id', 'test_suite_id'], 1, inplace=False)\
      .to_dict('records')
```

Result:

```
[{'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 1},
 {'test_case_id': 2, 'test_suite_id': 1},
 {'test_case_id': 3, 'test_suite_id': 1},
 {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 2},
 {'test_case_id': 2, 'test_suite_id': 2},
 {'test_case_id': 3, 'test_suite_id': 2},
 {'test_case_id': 1, 'test_suite_id': 3}]
```